# Displaying return from php script

Tags: php

I have this script:

```
/** Key */
private $k = 't0kJKx27zm4ronxqXe';

/** Private salt */
private $p = 't0kez47ARpOxFnoVNJ';

private $host = 'http://url.com';

public function __construct() 
{
   ;
}


public function generateUrl($iniciator = NULL)
{
    $token = hash_hmac('sha1', date('Y-m-d') . $this->k, $this->p);

    if($iniciator !== NULL)
    {
        if(!is_string($iniciator))
        {
            throw new \Exception('Iniciator must be string!');
        }
    }

    return $this->host . 'a=' . $this->a . '&k=' . $token . '&u=' . $iniciator;

}
}
```

How do i echo/print... the string in return?

> return $this->host . 'a=' . $this->a . '&k=' . $token . '&u=' . $iniciator;

Comment: `$class = new YourClassName(); echo $class->generateUrl();`

Comment: I suppose.
`echo generateUrl();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not complete it misses first line, something as:

```
class Test {
```

Then you would run your code with:

```
$someVar = new Test;
echo $someVar->generateUrl();
```

If you want to print from your class you can simply write echo instead of return:

```
echo $this->host . 'a=' . $this->a . '&k=' . $token . '&u=' . $iniciator;
```

And then you would run your code with:

```
$someVar = new Test;
$someVar->generateUrl(); // no need for echo because it's already in class
```

Warning: you have not defined variable $a in return.